# Сортировка строк сгенерированной матрицы (Python)

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка, numpy, матрицы

Необходимо применить разные способы сортировки к строкам сгенерированной матрицы (к примеру, сортировка выбором). Вопрос заключается в том, как в коде обозначить эти самые строки матрицы.

Код генерации матрицы:

```
import numpy as np

m = int(input("m: "))
n = int(input("n: "))
min_limit = int(input("min_limit: "))
max_limit = int(input("max_limit: "))
Z = np.random.randint(min_limit, max_limit, size=(m, n))
print(Z)
```

Comment: Z[0] - первая строка, Z[1] - вторая и т.д...

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html